# how can i get compilation, assembling, preprocessor and linking time separately for g++

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, compilation, g++

We are working on reducing build time for our code which have multiple libraries and cpp files . I want to check which step is taking more time out of compilation, assembling, preprocessor and linking. Is there any way i can get separate time for total project?

Please suggest. Any kind of help/pointer/suggestions will be appreciated. I am building using make on my debian system.

Comment: Explicitly do each step separately?

Comment: Also, why do you need to know this? Is there some underlying problem that leads to to believe you needs those times?

Comment: i tried doing separately but due to inter dependencies in libraries, i cannot build complete. Even i tried using -ftime-report option but is not helping much on linking and preprocessing time. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: compilation is taking more than 2 hours, although code is very big, but i need to figure out the problematic step first.

Comment: Does the build *always* take that long? Or just a full rebuild? If even changing a single source file cause a full rebuild or takes excessively long time, then consider compartmentalizing your build first of all, try to split as much as possible into independent units that can be built separately. Then for the main project it's basically a matter of linking the independent parts together, which should be quick unless you have hundreds of parts (libraries, static or shared) that needs to be linked.

Comment: full rebuild is taking time. changing file only rebuild that library. we have compartmentalized the project as much as we can, hence still we are looking into which compilation steps we should look more.. it is kind of build optimization steps we are performing, and needs to check which step we should target first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192343/discussion-between-vishwadeep-singh-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: Add some debugging output in the build process, and sit down with a stop-watch and time each module. If each module is quick enough then there's really much more you can do. Shaving a few seconds here and there might add up to a few minutes at most. And some modules might be slow just because there's just to much to do for that module. And unless you include hundreds of header files in a source file, or the source file is otherwise excessively large (tens of thousands of lines) building an object file from that source file is going to be quick enough.

Comment: yes. can we debug compilation with times for each different steps for compilation, assembling, preprocessor and linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `gcc`'s

> '-time[=FILE]'
>        Report the CPU time taken by each subprocess in the compilation
>        sequence.  For C source files, this is the compiler proper and
>        assembler (plus the linker if linking is done).
>
> Without the specification of an output file, the output looks like
>        this:
>
> ```
>   # cc1 0.12 0.01
>   # as 0.00 0.01
>
> …
> ```

?
(This is from [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html).)

Comment: thanks, this helps for most of the steps. still not able to log preprocessing step. Can i pull this data from -ftime-report?

Comment: Do you know for sure that you need it i.e. `cc1plus` (the compiler proper) is high on the profile? Anyway, the `-no-integrated-cpp` option seems to solve it for you. You'll see the compiler being called twice in the `-time` report: first with `-E` (that's the proprocessor) and then with `-fpreprocessed`.

Comment: Thanks much, this is the only option i was looking for.